# QGIS Printing to A0 plotter fails?

Tags: qgis, printing

HP5500PS A0 won't speak properly to QGIS.

When sending a plot via composer it plots a smaller print (less than A5 size) on an A0 piece of paper.

How can I get it to print an A0 map without changing it to pdf?

We produce A0 paper maps for our customers holding large datasets - too big to save to PDF and print off - quality degrades.

Comment: Why don't you want to print to PDF/PNG? That way you would see any rendering anomalies as well before printing and wasting ink.

Comment: Have you got all the page size settings right? Sorry if that's an obvious point, but a screenshot of the composition properties would show this. Also, what version of QGIS?

Comment: QGIS version 2.12.0-Lyon.  yes settings are correct in Composer AND in printer settings when the correct plotter is selected from the list.  we have checked printer settings and preferences for the selected plotter.

Comment: QGIS version 2.12.0-Lyon